# Setter method for Yii2 ActiveRecord relational attribute

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I'm puzzled by the way Yii2 active record handles relational attributes.  Is it possible to link an active-record object to another object without saving it first?

E.g., I'd like to add an image as a logo to a company record but haven't decided yet if both records should be saved.  Given a company

```
/**
 * @property integer $logo_id
 */
class Company extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public function getLogo()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Image::className(), ['id' => 'logo_id']);
    }
}
```

and an image

```
class Image extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    …
}
```

is there a simple way to set `$company->logo = new Image();` such that the image is saved together with the company the next time that `$company->save()` is called, but not before that?  In other words: I'm looking for the Yii2 equivalent of doing [`@logo = @company.build_image()` in rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-belongs-to-build-association-attributes).

As for now, I'm defining a logo setter function in the `Company` model.

```
public function setLogo(Image $image)
{
    // `link` expects the primary key to be present
    $image->id || $image->save();
    $this->link('logo', $image);
}
```

This obviously violates the principle of least astonishment, as the setter will not just modify the current object, but will effect (here: save) the parameter in possibly unexpected ways.  It seems like a terrible idea.

How can I do `$company->logo = new Image` without going against good design principles?

Comment: Are you uploading the image when you create the company?

Comment: @marche Sometimes, but it generally happens later (possibly never).

Comment: You can add a attribute inside your Company model that holds the temporary logo and modify it later, but i can't help you more if you don't explain the kind of workflow you wish to accomplish.

Comment: @marche I appreciate your offer to check the complete workflow, but company policy doesn't allow me to discuss this here.  For the moment, I'm primary interested in solving this specific problem.  Using a separate attribute to hold the temporary logo would certainly work, but it seems quite inelegant.  It would give us two attributes where one should be enough.

Comment: You could also use a separate model that holds all the fields you need, and at the end when it's decided to save both the company and the logo to the database. This model can be similar to the LoginForm model that comes by default with new Yii2 installations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are 2 successive requests that need to be sent to database any way.

> without going against good design principles?

[link()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#link()-detail) and [unlink()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#unlink()-detail) are meant to relate or unrelate 2 already existing models by setting their relative foreign keys within a **db** request (within or without *junction table*). [unlink()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#unlink()-detail) can even delete the related record if its *$delete* attribute is set to true. so related data must be first created with valid *id* before relating them within a second request.

The [link()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#link()-detail) method will throw a `yii\base\InvalidCallException` if the models cannot be linked. That is good but it will NOT perform any data validation while saving the affected Active Record instance. In the other side, the [save()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#save()-detail) method will perform validation by default but won't throw http exceptions if something goes wrong.

So if I have to use the [link()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#link()-detail) method, I would link models within **CONTROLLER** action rather than model classes after being sure that related model is saved (or exist by trying to retrieve it) then I'll be sure that exceptions will be thrown if something won't work as expected :

```
if ($image->save() === false && !$image->hasErrors()) {
    throw new ServerErrorHttpException('Failed for some reason.');
}
$company->link('logo', $image);
```

- You may also use
  [Transaction](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-transaction.html#begin()-detail)
  if multi-requests have to be sent and should be saved properly or rolled back if they don't like
  [in this
  example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26856663/yii2-save-related-records-in-single-save-call-in-single-transaction#answer-29005763).

---

Otherwise I'll probably save the related model and just assign its new *id* attribute to current model. I don't see any need to use the [link()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#link()-detail) method inside the model class and send one more request to **db** if I know that my model is going to be saved later any way by invoking its `save()` method :

```
public function setLogo(Image $image)
{
    if (!$image->id && $image->save() === false){
        throw new yii\base\UserException('Failed for some reason');
    }
    $this->logo_id = $image->getPrimaryKey();
}
```

Or within your controller you can simply do somthing like :

```
$image = new Image();
if ($image->save()) // or maybe throw exceptions
$company->logo_id = $image->getPrimaryKey();
```

Without having to write any extra function for it. It will be related when calling `$company->save()`

---

> Is it possible to link an active-record object to another object
>   without saving it first?

A different approach is by holding the image instance somewhere, like a public or private property until you decide if you are going to save it according to maybe some future logic. In that case, [beforeSave](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#beforeSave%28%29-detail) method which will be triggered before *insert* or *update* may be a good place to do so :

```
private $_image;

public function getImage()
{
    return $this->_image;
}

public function setImage(Image $image)
{
    $this->_image = $image;
}

public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if ($this->_image->id){
        $this->logo_id = $this->_image->id;
    }

    // otherwise you may save it as previous examples
    // before assigning its returned id to $this->logo_id
    // it will be good to have also plans for unexpected errors

    return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}
```

Then any where when doing `$company->image = new Image` the image instance will live with it until `$company->save()` or `$company->update()` are invoked.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the throughout answer! Especially the explanation of idiomatic ways to handle situations like this is great.  Coming from rails, I find it unusual to do so much work in the controller, though It does seem like reasonable thing to do here.

Comment: Oh, the pleasure was mine. I did learn few more things in the process of answering your question ! I had also curiosity about how rails handle those situations, so thanks for asking & welcome to Yii !

Comment: This introduces a lot of magic/ambigious attributes. I would prefer your save is as much 1-on-1 as possible.